# Embed subset in a table function

Tags: r

Unlike Stata and other statistical package, running a cross tabulation on a subset of data in R is not a very straight forward thing.
Let us assume the following scenario: assuming I want to cross tabulate Sex (M, F) by Tobacco (1 - Current, 2-Ex, 3-Never), but by excluding the Never smoking category. In stata a simple if Tobacco!=3 would suffice. However in R we need to subset the data prior to tabulating it:

```
{r}
#subsetting the data
retinol1<-subset(retinol, tabac!=3)
table(retinol1$Sex, retinol1$tabac)
```

is there a way to subset the data directly in 1 step?

Thank you

Comment: Try `with(subset(retinol, tabac!=3), table(Sex, tabac))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`xtabs()` has a subset argument so one option is to use that instead of `table()`.

```
xtabs(~ Sex + tabac, retinol, subset = tabac != 3)
```